# Create or cut 6 equal parts from a bitmap not working

Tags: android, view, bitmap

In my app I am having a method which cuts the 6 equal parts from a bitmap given to it. It works fine with the bitmap in square but does not work with rectangle bitmaps.

Here is the method.

```
public Bitmap[] splitBitmap6(Bitmap picture) {
    int w = picture.getWidth();
    int h = picture.getHeight();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    int widthofmainBitMap  = screenWidth ;
    int heightofmainBitMap = widthofmainBitMap*h/w;

    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, widthofmainBitMap, heightofmainBitMap, true);

    Bitmap[] imgs = new Bitmap[];

    imgs[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, picture.getWidth()/3 , picture.getHeight()/2);
    imgs[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, picture.getWidth()/3, 0, picture.getWidth()/3,picture.getHeight()/2);
// i get the error at this line

    imgs[2] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap,((picture.getWidth()/3)+(picture.getWidth()/3)), 0, picture.getWidth()/3,picture.getHeight()/2);
    imgs[3] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, (picture.getHeight()/2), picture.getWidth()/3, picture.getHeight()/2);
    imgs[4] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, picture.getWidth()/3, picture.getHeight()/2, picture.getWidth()/3,picture.getHeight()/2);
    imgs[5] = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, (picture.getWidth()/3)+(picture.getWidth()/3), picture.getHeight()/2,picture.getWidth()/3,picture.getHeight()/2);

    return imgs;
}
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.illegalargumentexception: x + width must be <= bitmap.width.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `picture.getWidth()` and `picture.getHeight()`. However, you have scaled `picture` and stored it in `scaledBitmap`.

The dimensions of `picture` are not same as the dimensions of `scaledBitmap`. Therefore the above exception is being thrown.

You should be using: `scaledBitmap.getWidth()` and `scaledBitmap.getHeight()` instead.

**Alternatively:**

Set `picture` = `scledBitmap` as follows:

```
...
...
scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, widthofmainBitMap, heightofmainBitMap, true);
picture = scaledBitmap;
...
...
// rest remains same
```